# Display best selling products from a category

Tags: product, category, best-seller

How can I display the 10 best selling products of a category on a specific page or block?

I want to load this inside the category as an entire new page.

Comment: Did you get your point?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with best selling products is, that there is no way to get them, except getting all order items and count them. More orders, means more work.

The first question is:

1. What is a best selling item?

If it is the product which is sold the most, since the shop went online, I would add an `int` attribute `times_sold` to save the qty of sold items.

Then I would write a cron job, which updates this field every night, either by summing up all orders or by updating it based on the last day. If you are doing it by way 2, you want consider, that your cron job might not run one time and think about how to know, which order is already counted and which not, so for the moment (and depening on the mass of orders), I would count all orders every night.

After you have this attribute, you can just order by it, when `used_for_sort_by` is set to `true`

Comment: By SQL query how can i do that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. do what?

Comment: How can i display Level 2 category(eg. Book-> Tamil -> Harry Potter, here Book is level 2 category) wise best selling products?

Comment: Doing it in SQL is horrible slow. Don't do that.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to show the current category best selling add this to $_productCollection

```
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'))
```

if you want the best selling for a specific category add this before $_productCollection

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
```

((4) is the id of the category) and then in the $_productCollection add

```
->addCategoryFilter($_category)
```

Comment: How exactly should this filter anything for a best selling product?